# Fourier transform and complex vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, fourier-transform

It is known that the Fourier transform, continuous and discrete, can be interpreted as a change of basis. The basis is the one formed by complex exponentials.

Each basis vector is a complex exponential of different (integer or real for the continuous FT) frequency, yes?

Can we say that these basis vectors (complex exponentials) for that basis of a Complex vector space ?

Can you confirm/correct/formalize my statements? (The difficulty here is the notion of complex vector space)

*(For the DFT (1D) I like to see it as a matrix multiplication (2D DFT matrix with basis vectors in each row times 1D vector in time domain).

More concretely, for the DFT, if we have 8 vectors, each containing 8 points of complex exponentials of different frequencies (all orthogonal to each other), i.e., in Matlab:

```
B=dftmtx(8)
```

can we safely say that those 8 vectors form a basis of $\mathbb{C}^8$ ?!

Comment: "It is known that the Fourier transform, continuous and discrete, can be interpreted as a change of basis. The basis is the one formed by complex exponentials." Not in general, no. For example, complex exponentials are not even elements of $L^1(\Bbb R)$, so they're not likely to  form a basis...

Comment: Can you develop please. For example it is the case that it is a change of basis for the DFT right ?

Comment: Yes, "complex exponentials", or more properly _characters_, form a basis (for $L^1(G)$) if $G$ is a compact abelian group, in particular if $G$ is finite, which is  the case for the DFT. (A hint for the question at the end of your post: Orthonormal functions are linearly independent.)

Comment: Thanks, I never heard of the term 'characters' in this context, is it something related to 'modes' (i ve heard refering to DFT basis vectors as 'modes' instead of basis vectors). Roughly, can we say Fourier modes $\simeq$ Fourier basis vectors ?

Comment: I have no idea what those "modes" might be, sorry. If $G$ is a (locally compact abelian) group a character of $G$ is a continuous homomorphism from $G$ to $\Bbb T$.

Comment: There is a reference to these 'modes' here: http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/~sws02hs/teaching/Fourier/Fourier_2_student.pdf

Comment: I don't understand your explanation about Groups. I know groups a a kind of algebraic structures, i.e. a set+operations+axioms, and abelian=commutative, but why/how exactly do you know the DFT is a group? It would help me if you can define what is the set of G and the operations maybe?